# Jetty starting on first available port

Tags: junit, jetty

I have several junit tests that need Jetty. Every test uses an instance of Jetty. However, the tests can be added ad-hoc, but if two Jetty servers use the same port then the test will fail because the port is already in use. The error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (start-jetty) on project petproject1: Failure: Address already in use -> [Help 1]
```

So what I am looking for is a way to start Jetty on the first available port starting from port X  (8080 or more?) instead of having a big table with all start ports for every test.

Answer (score 0):

a) You can superclass your tests and implement some sort of port counter in that superclass, which is incremented in each @Before (which, I suppose, manages the setup of a jettyy)
b) You can start jetty with port 0 (which is a random free port), and then ask jetty instance for the port number in each test (if you have access to it in your test, if not: use @Rule)